# Write a line on over mouse pointer and move with it

Tags: python, xlib

I'm writing an application for accessibility purposes and need to draw a line that follow the mouse movements on top of all windows, and the problem I'm facing is that after I make the mouse move the line some time later disappears so it's very difficult for the user to see the line. I can only use python-xlib

```
def createAbsoluteMouseEvent(x,y):
    #move pointer to set absolute location
    dis = display.Display()
    scr = dis.screen()
    win = scr.root
    data = win.get_geometry()
    height = data.height
    if lineActive:
        colormap = scr.default_colormap
        color = colormap.alloc_color(cred, cgreen, cblue)
        gc = win.create_gc(
            line_width = lineWidth,
            line_style = X.LineSolid,
            fill_style = X.FillOpaqueStippled,
            fill_rule  = X.WindingRule,
            cap_style  = X.CapButt,
            join_style = X.JoinMiter,
            foreground = color.pixel,
            background = scr.black_pixel,
            graphics_exposures = True,
            subwindow_mode = X.IncludeInferiors,
        )
        win.line(gc, x, 0, x, height)
    win.warp_pointer(x,y)
    dis.sync()
```

Comment: can you define a pointer which includes your line? (instead of trying to draw line on overlay window, which would require Composite extension)

Comment: maybe but i need to make that the pointer be able to change color and widht and indicates where the pointer is for example with perpendicular line. Is there any example with the pointer or with composite?

Comment: You can have any 32 bit pixmap as a cursor with XRenderCreateCursor

Comment: what's the equivalent on python xlib?

Comment: looks like it's not supported by core python-xlib, but you can use this separate extansion to it - https://github.com/alexer/python-xlib-render/blob/master/render.py#L771

Comment: i can't apply the patch that is provided with the extension the patch gave me the following error patch -p1 < object-fix.patch
patching file Xlib/protocol/rq.py
Hunk #1 succeeded at 523 (offset 8 lines).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 548.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 557.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 603.
Hunk #5 succeeded at 831 (offset -6 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 843 (offset -6 lines).
3 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file Xlib/protocol/rq.py.rej

Comment: do you have any simple example with composite extension for drawing a line?

Comment: only in javascript using node-x11

Comment: could you pass me that example and y figured out how to translate to python